# how to clear cache in CachedNetworkImage flutter

Tags: android, caching, flutter

i dont want to store image in cache.. iam using CachedNetworkImage for image loading..
I want know is there any option to remove or do not store image in cache like picasso..

my code:

```
var annotatedImg = CachedNetworkImage(
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
      imageUrl: Constants.IMAGE_BASE_URL + widget._fileId + Constants.CONTOUR_IMG_SUFFIX,
      placeholder: (context, url) => progressBar,
      errorWidget: (context, url, error) => new Icon(Icons.error),
    );
```

i have tried

```
annotatedImg.cacheManager.emptyCache();
```

but its shows cant call emptyCache is null..

Comment: It is so frustrated that there is no info nor code just to delete or replace the freaking one cache file I really need to do :/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Firstly add the package (flutter_cache_manager) to pubspec.yaml file as following:

dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
***flutter_cache_manager: ^1.1.3***

After a day, I found the solution. Use the DefaultCacheManager object by calling emptyCache() method, this clears the cache data.

```
DefaultCacheManager manager = new DefaultCacheManager();
manager.emptyCache(); //clears all data in cache.
```

Answer (score 30):

Since CachedNetworkImage **version 2.3**, all these solutions **won't work** because it cached images in 2 different places (DefaultCacheManager & NetworkImageProvider)

So the only solution is using the `evictFromCache` built-in method from `CachedNetworkImage`

like this:

```
Future _deleteImageFromCache() async {
    String url = "your url";
    await CachedNetworkImage.evictFromCache(url);
  }
```

`evictFromCache` is a Static method so it doesn't require to have the `CachedNetworkImage` in your Widget tree, you can use it directly from any place.

Comment: where to call this method

Answer (score 23):

I agree with MichaelM, Don't use CachedNetworkImage.If you show image like this :

```
Image.network(
      _headImageUrl,
      fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
    )
```

you can use those code to clean image cache:

```
PaintingBinding.instance.imageCache.clear();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. I was struggling for three months with images that I deleted but they kept appearing on the screen. I was so frustrated because that didn't make any sense to me. After I saw your answer, I added **PaintingBinding.instance.imageCache.clear()** after I deleted the images and it finally worked. Again, thank you so much man, this really helped me.

Comment: This clears the entire image cache. Better just remove the one image provider like this: `_imgProvider = NetworkImage(url); _imgProvider.evict();`
Be sure to evict it from cache _before_ loading the image.

Answer (score 14):

`import 'package:flutter_cache_manager/flutter_cache_manager.dart';
 await DefaultCacheManager().removeFile('YOUR_URL');`

DONT USE emptyCache() from the first answer, it clear ALL your Cache

Comment: It doesn't  clear cache if the app isn't restarted. Any way to solve that too ?

Comment: @SteevJames for me it works without restarting the application!

Answer (score 4):

CachedNetworkImage stores the images in temporary(cache) folder, you can get access to it with `path_provider`'s `getTemporaryDirectory()` method. There you will find `libCachedImageData` (You might need to check the name). There you can delete the folder.

To do it in your app you should use Directory class like:

```
final Directory tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
final Directory libCacheDir = new Directory("${tempDir.path}/libCachedImageData");
await libCacheDir.delete(recursive: true);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to store the downloaded image in a cache, then don't use `CachedNetworkImage`. Instead, use a [`FadeInImage`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FadeInImage-class.html) widget with a NetworkImage:

```dart
FadeInImage(
  // here `bytes` is a Uint8List containing the bytes for the in-memory image
  placeholder: // This should be an image, so you can't use progressbar,
  image: NetworkImage('https://backend.example.com/image.png'),
)
```

Comment: i want to progress bar in placeholder

Answer (score 1):

In your CachedNetworkImage, add CacheManager Config:

```
CachedNetworkImage(CacheManager(Config(
              featureStoreKey,
              stalePeriod: const Duration(seconds: 15),
              maxNrOfCacheObjects: 1,
              repo: JsonCacheInfoRepository(databaseName: featureStoreKey),
              fileService: HttpFileService(),
            ),
        ),
  fit: BoxFit.fill,
  imageUrl: Constants.IMAGE_BASE_URL + widget._fileId + Constants.CONTOUR_IMG_SUFFIX,
  placeholder: (context, url) => progressBar,
  errorWidget: (context, url, error) => new Icon(Icons.error),
);
```

Then to clear it, add this void statement:

```
void _clearCache() {
try {
  JsonCacheInfoRepository(databaseName: featureMain1Store).deleteDataFile();
} catch (e, s) {
  print(s);
}
imageCache!.clear();
imageCache!.clearLiveImages();
setState(() {});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1- for CachedNetworkImage library

```
`CachedNetworkImage(
    imageUrl: "https://www.fluttercampus.com/img/logo_small.webp",
    placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
    errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
    cacheManager: CacheManager(
        Config(
          "fluttercampus",
          stalePeriod: const Duration(days: 7),
          //one week cache period
        )
    ),
)`
```

you can use one of those

`await DefaultCacheManager().removeFile("fluttercampus");`

`await CachedNetworkImage.evictFromCache('YOUR_URL');`

don't use this cause it will delete all data in CacheManager

`await DefaultCacheManager().emptyCache();`

2- if you want to delete from Image.network use this

```
Image.network(
      _headImageUrl,
      fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
    )
```

you can use those code to clean image cache:

```
PaintingBinding.instance.imageCache.clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to test my widget that uses `CachedNetworkWidget`, but without using the existing cache.

Adding `CachedNetworkImage.evictFromCache` in the `imageBuilder` did the job:

```
 return CachedNetworkImage(
    imageUrl: widget.item.img_url,
    imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) {
      if (kDebugMode) CachedNetworkImage.evictFromCache(widget.item.img_url);

      //...rest of the code
    },
  );
```